# Simulation result graph in Anylogic

Tags: plot, time, graph, simulation, anylogic

Please help!!!
Time Plot with Anylogic is not showing the complete curb of the graph. I would like to know if someone could help to get the complete trace of the graph right from time t = t0 to t= tn. Please see the screenshot below. What has happened to the other part of the graph initially? It keeps moving so fast and end up showing only at the end of the simulation time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Increase the number shown in the picture below
[image]

Comment: Emile Zankoul thanks a lot. It seems to be working. I will get back if there is another complication. God bless you.